# How to put non-scrollable UITableView in UIScrollView correctly?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview, storyboard

**What I want**
I try to add a non-scrollable TableView into a ScrollView, but I failed to succeed, so I need your help.
The reason for this is I want to have an Info page, with some info in it and a list of users in a TableView and maybe some other UI elements below the TableView. I use only the Storyboard for that, because I don’t like to layout views programmatically.

**Strategy**
The page can be longer than the screen window can fit in, hence a ScrollView, so the user can scroll up to show more content. To show a list of users, I want to make use of a TableView, that’s the first thing that comes into my mind and I think it’s quite logic to use a TableView for that. The idea is that if more rows are added dynamically, the longer the TableView grows and that information is somehow passed back to the ScrollView that on his turn adjusts its height.

**Test**
So I was experimenting and tested for some reason first with a UITextView that contains a dynamic text, which works as expected. If I put some long text in it, the page can scroll up and down to show all the content. But after testing it with a TableView the result was not I want. I found out the TableView has a fixed height that doesn’t seem to change dynamically when adding rows. As a result, the TableView shows just 2 rows instead of 10, because the TableView doesn’t grow. I turned off the TableView’s property ‘Scrolling Enabled’ as I did for UITextView.

**Question**
TableView doesn’t grow as more rows are added. I’m not sure why, but I didn’t add a height constraint to fix the height of the TableView. So why doesn’t TableView grow?

**Image:**
[image: ScrollView with TextView and TableView]

**Source for some tutorials:**
https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/
https://medium.com/rocknnull/ios-working-with-uiscrollview-uitextview-and-auto-layout-afa39fe2cac8
https://medium.com/disblu/scroll-view-auto-layout-in-xcode-8-7f43e82fe33

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a single tableView. What you need to do is to use customCell.

**How to do it?**

According to your design what you shared lets say you have three different types of thing.

1. Blue Cell(Containing Info)
2. Green Cell (I don't know it's purpose. :))
3. User cell.

So basically you need three types of different CustomCell and 
in **CellForRowAtIndexPath** method  call like this:

```
if(indexpath.row == 0) {
    return BlueCell;
    }
else if(indexpath.row == 1) {
    return GreenCell;
}
else {
    return UserCell;
}
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: That's a solution I'll use that for now, thnx. However, I'm so frustrated that what I tried to accomplish doesn't work I just can't let it go, it feels like I've wasted so much time and failed.

Comment: It's not an exact answer to my question, just another solution, so +1 for that ;)